# references are missing. Ensure project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.web' & PreserveCompilationContext property is not set to false

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am getting this error while trying to run the asp.net core project.

**One or more compilation references are missing. Ensure project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.web' & PreserveCompilationContext property is not set to false**

[image]

**EfDemo.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
namespace EfDemo.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        async public Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            using (var context = new EFCoreWebDemoContext())
            {
                var model = await context.Authors.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
                return View(model);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EFCoreWebDemoContext.cs**

```
public class EFCoreWebDemoContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
       optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"connection string");
    }
 }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div>
    <span>Home Page</span>
</div>
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - EfDemo</title>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**_ViewImports.cshtml**

```
@using EfDemo
@using EfDemo.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.NET.Sdk
```

Added breakpoint and checked while executing the application it crashes on return View(model); in **HomeController.cs** file

Tried modifying the **HomeController.cs** shown below but still the same issue.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: The problem appears to be in the runtime compilation of the view.  Can you post your cshtml too.

Comment: @Neil added cshtml files .... please check it

Answer (score 3):

The `Reference Versions` are conflict.

I suggest you try modify `csproj` like below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: In PackageReference `SqlServer, Tools, Design` are downgraded to lower version so should I downgrade it to make it work

Comment: Yes, you could downgrade to `2.0.*` version from `NuGet`. Your `TargetFramework` is `netcoreapp2.0`, so, you need to keep your reference as `2.0.*`

Answer (score 1):

Updated **csproj** file with below packages and updated visual studio to 15.7.5 which wokred

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Your issue is caused by different reference version and targetframework version. Downgrading the reference or upgrading your project to `netcoreapp2.1`, both will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error after I updated the visual studio. To resolve I install latest SDK from this page: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download. And then switch my project to latest .net core (in my case it was 2.2). In VS then I clean my solution and rebuild it. And then updated my references using "Tools ->> Nuget Package Manager ->> manage nuget packages for solution."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was able to solve the following as I uninstalled the packages in nuget and installed again. After that I compiled the project and it all worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my published deployed code on server, even there was no issue on local development machine.

I resolved this issue by replacing old **MyWebProject.deps.json** file by updated one on server, hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was this package, 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design'
which was creating the issue. After I removed it, It is working well.